# Wrong number of argument: lambda (lst1 lst 2) when extend a list

Tags: elisp

I tried the `append` method of a list in elisp

```
#+BEGIN_SRC elisp :session sicp
(defun append(lst1 lst2)
  (if (null lst1)
      lst2
      (cons (car lst1) (append (cdr lst1) lst2))))
(defvar lst1 (list 1 2 3 4))
(defvar lst2 (list 11 12 13 14))
(append lst1 lst2)
#+END_SRC
```

It report error:

```
Wrong number of argument: lambda (lst1 lst 2).....(append (cdr lst1) lst2)))), 7
```

What's the problem?

Comment: `append` is a system function, please use a different name.

Comment: please copy and paste the exact error. this is not what emacs can give you.